# showing profile photo after logging in

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created a login page and an external login using google. the registration and login forms are working fine and when the user is logged in the profile photo is appearing fine but my problem is with google. The user will be signed in ok and the user profile information are saved in the database table but the profile photo will generate an error.

below is how i save the google account profile info:

```
[Route("google-response")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GoogleResponse()
{

    var google_csrf_name = "g_csrf_token";
    var cookie = Request.Cookies[google_csrf_name];
    if (cookie == null)
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var requestbody = Request.Form[google_csrf_name];

    if (requestbody != cookie)
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var idtoken = Request.Form["credential"];
    GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload = await    GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(idtoken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    byte[] y = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload.Picture);

    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = payload.Email, Email = payload.Email , 
        firstName = payload.GivenName, lastName = payload.FamilyName, PictureSource = y, EmailConfirmed=true
    };
    await _userManager.CreateAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    //add role
    await _signManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Dashboard");

}
```

the sidebar

```
 @* change based on login *@ 
 @if (!SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
 {
     
     <div class="profile-wrapper">
         <img class="profile-pic" src="~/profile.jpg" />
         <div class="titles d-flex flex-column ps-3">
             <h6 class="mb-0">Expense Tracher</h6>
             <span class="text-muted">Guest</span>
         </div>
     </div>
 }
 else
 {
         <div class="profile-wrapper">
             <img style="width:40px;height:40px; object-fit:cover; border-radius:30px" src="data:image/*;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)?.Result.PictureSource))">
             <div class="titles d-flex flex-column ps-3">
                 <h6 class="mb-0">Expense Tracher</h6>
                 <span class="text-muted">@User.Identity?.Name</span>
             </div>
         </div>
 }
```

Comment: in this line the error triggered only if i login with google. 
<img style="width:40px;height:40px; object-fit:cover; border-radius:30px" src="data:image/*;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)?.Result.PictureSource))">

Comment: How you add the google authentication? Asp.net core default identity with google external authentication?  When you debug the application, does the y contains the picture information and are you make sure the picture data has stored into the database?